# Ruby Third-Party Dependencies in Custom Puppet Providers

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am not so familiar with Ruby and native custom type development in Puppet, but I cannot find any hints what is the right way of getting modules running that require other ruby gems. I have implemented a custom provider that requires `rest-client` and  `nokogiri`.

For test purposes I put the module to a specific location und used `puppet apply --modulepath=... site.pp`. Of course, the run fails because `rest-client` and  `nokogiri` and are not available on the test host. I can install the gems manually via `gem install rest-client nokogiri` and everythings works, but I am trying to create a fully automated provision process.

What is the right approach for getting those modules running automatically. In the final scenario, the modules are located at the puppetmaster. Are `rest-client` and  `nokogiri` required to be present on server- or client-side and how can I make sure that those gems are installed automatically when the module gets used?

Comment: If you need to manage some application by puppet, always check puppet forge first https://forge.puppetlabs.com/. And try to find there dedicated puppet module. There is one for nokogiri https://forge.puppetlabs.com/tags/nokogiri

Comment: If I get you right, the way it goes is to define e.g. a package dependency on `rest_client` and `nokigiri` (provider `gem`) in order to make sure that those packages are present before my module gets executed. Right?

Comment: @Herr-Herner yes. you will either need to install the gems manually or use puppet itself to ensure the gems are installed via a `package` resource.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of right now, "Puppet module `metadata.json` currently are only concerned with module dependencies," and can't configure gems ([PUP-3386](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3386)).

There was [an email discussion on Puppet Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/fScJS3KRZHM) about this at the end of last year as well.